# Reversible unique constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I'm looking to add a unique constraint to a 2 columns table that would be reversible.
In other words, if I have:

```
Table Linking
-------------
Link1 | Link2
-------------
1     |   2
```

The above entry would be considered the same as:

```
Table Linking
-------------
Link1 | Link2
-------------
2     |   1
```

... so I don't want to be able to insert the second case.

Not sure if this is possible, but if so thank you for your help!

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could compute link_min = min(link1, link2) and link_max = max(link1, link2) and put a unique constraint on (link_min, link_max).

Or you could put in a constraint CHECK(link1 < link2) and always have the links in that order.